# Is there a way to play YouTube without opening a tab in browser?

Tags: windows, windows-10, youtube

Previously I am using the Upnext Player to play YouTube music in background. However, it was removed from Chrome store. I continued using it as unpacked extension in developer mode, until recently it cannot play music normally for unknown reason.

[Link to Github of Upnext player](https://github.com/ptgamr/upnext)

I constantly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to switch between tab, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>to switch between applications, so having a browser or an application that is not in the background is really distracting for me. Is there an alternative to the Upnext Player?

P.S. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This MakeUseOf [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/extensions-make-youtube-powerful-music-player-need/) lists a number of alternative Chrome extensions, but the only one that appears to still be available in the Google Play store is [Play Tube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/playtube/mgcacknkafhdpbnfiokajkfcaldpdnbl?ref=producthunt).

Otherwise perhaps a Windows 10 app might be more to your liking? Perfect Tube seems to get a decent review in the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Play Tube is still in the Google Play, but it is not working if you try installing and use it.

Comment: Yeah, was going to recommend checking the Windows Store. This is one of the few things for which it's really well suited.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes